# Input traffic spikes on outside interface at same time every day

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa

For the last two days I've had this issue where our internet connection SLOWS to a crawl and is almost unusable.  I logged into our Cisco ASA 5500 (not very well versed with it) but I was able to see out Input traffic on our Outside interface has SPIKED significantly (screenshot):

[image]

Also I noticed that our HTTP traffic is using the majority of our traffic (which is unusal).

[image]

How can I find out where this spike in traffic is coming from? And who is responsible? Which of our clients or workstation? Or any outside IPs?  I noticed it started at almost exactly 11am yesterday, and today. If you need more info please let me know, I'm a bit rattled at the moment trying to figure this out.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know that on that screenshot there is no spike? Just two almost flat lines. If you want to show a spike, we need a context..

Comment: There is quite a spike.  Normal usage is around 2000kbs. I just didn't get the screenshot until after the spike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the next tabs... 'Top 10 Sources' and 'Top 10 Destinations' and identify the internal device from the IP.

I would guess someone set up a remote backup or similar scheduled task.